# Css Animation Flashesh for a second before it starts on mobile devices

Tags: css, animation, jquery-animate, animate.css

I'm using animate.css and animate-plus.js to animate elements on the page when scrolling, the problem is that on mobile devices element flashes for a fraction of second before it starts and it ruins the effect.I should mention that it works fine on desktops

Here is my code :

```
<div class="col-md-12 animate-plus animated hidden-load " data-animations="fadeInLeft"  data-animation-when-visible="true"> 
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
</div>
```

I've tried some solution forom other user on stackoverflow who had similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23709439/how-to-hide-animated-elements-on-load)
I've used :

```
.hidden-load {visibility: hidden; opacity: 0}
.hidden-load.animated {visibility: visible; opacity: 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this below:

```
$('#XXX').css({"opacity":0}).delay(200).css({"opacity":1});
```